# Flutter YoutubePlayer lagging inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a ListView of posts each post can contain a youtube video so I used **youtube_player_flutter** package to render the youtube video on each post.

The problem happened on scrolling the ListView it became **laggy** and **slow** after adding the youtube player. Also I've noticed that the placed youtube videos are **loaded automatically** on building the list even if I've disabled the autoPlay tag.

```
  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: posts.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, i) => const YoutubePlayerWidget(videoUrl: posts[i].video!),
  );

class YoutubePlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? videoId;
  final String? videoUrl;

  const YoutubePlayerWidget({super.key, this.videoId, this.videoUrl});

  @override
  State<YoutubePlayerWidget> createState() => _YoutubePlayerWidgetState();
}

class _YoutubePlayerWidgetState extends State<YoutubePlayerWidget> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.videoId ?? YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.videoUrl!)!,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: false,
        mute: true,
        isLive: false,
        disableDragSeek: true,
        loop: false,
        forceHD: false,
      ),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayer(controller: _controller);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some workaround here to optimise the list.

- Instead of adding the player into each listView items, replace the video player with the thumbnail image.
- Add gestureDetector on the image to get the details of video and show the video player and relevant widgets over the same image using `Stack` widget where hide the Video player with a boolean conditional so that it DOES NOT appear in the Widget tree initially.

  ```
   Stack(
     children: [
        Image.network('youtube-thumbnail-url'),
        Positioned(
          child: YoutubePlayerWidget(
          videoUrl: posts[i].video!,
           ),
        )
     ],
   ),
  ```

Manage the position of the video player using the `Positioned` widget. You may try with `Positioned.fill` as well depending on your requirement.

> How to get the thumbnail image from the video id:

`https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg`

To optimise the thumbnail path take help of this post

[Get Thumbnail of YouTube Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743525/flutter-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video)